# Pinch interface on Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to ask this of developers that have more experience than I do. I am only a junior programmer and have worked with Java, C, and VB.net. I have been asked if it is possible to create something similar to the iOS Pinch interface, but for Android. I am pretty sure this is possible but have no starting point to work with. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.diginfo.tv/v/12-0202-r-en.php

Possible approaches I see are to either have a high-end device, like a multicore tablet host the original video or rendering, and then stream parts to other devices via Wifi, or to do this from a PC.